# Using Robot framework with Google Chrome browser

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am running test scripts in Robot framework using Google Chrome browser.
But when I run scripts consecutively two times, no message log gets generated in message log section in Run tab. This problem is being encountered only while using Chrome.

Can anyone help me on this as why it is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the test with 'pybot -L TRACE' ?